# Crontab past the hour

Tags: cron

For testing purposes ,I would like to run a command check every 15 minutes past the hour.
I'm a little bit confused about the correct timeframe syntax of the crontab :

Is this correct :

```
*/15 * * * *
```

or

this one :

```
15 * * * *
```

I think its the first one ,since the second will run 15 minutes (once) after 1 hour passed.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The first one will (with most common `cron` implementations) run the command every 15 minutes and is equivalent to `0,15,30,45 * * * *`.

The second one will run 15 minutes past the hour, every hour.

This is described in the `crontab(5)` manual on your system (`man 5 crontab`).

Comment: @VorX I think I slightly misread your question and have amended the answer... I hope that it's still clear.

Answer (score 2):

Your first crontab line means running a command every 15 minutes.

The second one means running a command 15 minutes after every hour.

Answer (score 0):

The first one will execute at every 15th minute, that is xxh15; xxh30; xxh45; (xx + 1)h00.

The second one will execute at minute 15. Ex: xxh15; (xx + 1)h15; (xx + 2)h15.

If you have any doubts in how to set a crontab I recommed you to check the [crontab guru](http://crontab.guru).

Answer (score -4):

This one is correct

```
*/15 * * * *
```

Also, check the [crontab.guru website](https://crontab.guru/#*/15_*_*_*_*).

Comment: It depends on how you interpret "every 15 minutes past the hour" in the question. It's either "every 15 minutes" or "15 minutes past every hour".